# Expanding a html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I scroll down the mouse, more content are loaded in html page. Is there any way that I can expand the whole html page so that all content will be loaded in one go?

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

The above code helps me to get the new content of html page but also it redirect me to the bottom of page. Is there any way to stay on top of the page and using **scrollto** function or any other way to get the whole content in one go?

Comment: You could try scrolling back to position 0 right after going to the bottom. But that may cancel the first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly there are ajax requests being sent for the content to get loaded, so I don't think there's any way to get all content in one go.

As we scroll down & reach the bottom an ajax request is sent for more content and it repeats. Since, there's no way to combine all ajax requests in one go, unless you have write permission to the webpage, all that can be done is scrolling.

Of course, scroll back up when scrolled down, might appear like a bit of flickering in some browsers(may be not).